# Re-writing a sub-select as a condition on a column generated with 'over (partition by ...)'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, window-functions

I am wondering if it would be possible to use `over (partition by...)` clause in order to avoid using a sub-select in the example below:

```
declare @t table (
     id         int
    ,code       char(2)
    ,descriptor int
)

insert into @t
      select 1, 'a1', 10
union select 1, 'a1', 20
union select 1, 'a1', 30
union select 2, 'b1', 10
union select 2, 'b1', 20
union select 2, 'b1', 30
union select 2, 'b2', 10
union select 2, 'b2', 20
union select 2, 'b2', 30
union select 3, 'c4', 10
union select 3, 'c4', 20
union select 3, 'c4', 30
union select 3, 'c7', 10
union select 3, 'c7', 20
union select 3, 'c7', 30


select *
from @t as t
where code = (select min(code) from @t where id = t.id)
```

I want to see only the records with the `code` equal to `a1`, `b1` and `c4`. Can `over (partition by...)` assign 1 to all those and 2 to `b2` and `c7` codes, etc, so that at the end I could say `where row_number = 1` instead of using a sub-query?

Comment: the `over (partition by...)` thing is called a "window function".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way (that meets the requirements and is compatible with 2005+ but should likely not ever be used in practice) is

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties id,
                       code,
                       descriptor
FROM   t
WHERE  id IS NOT NULL
       AND code IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY RANK()
            OVER (PARTITION BY id
                      ORDER BY code);
```

Whilst a fun answer (ab)using `TOP` in this way is less efficient than simply using some form of derived table and filtering in the `WHERE` however.

And you won't be able to apply any additional ordering to the results of this query without wrapping it in a table expression anyway. As the current `ORDER BY` must be unchanged to avoid altering the results.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e16a2/8)

Answer (score 9):

Yes but not with `row_number()`. You can use either the window aggregate `min()`:

```
select id, code, descriptor
from 
  ( select id, code, descriptor, 
           min_code = min(code) over (partition by id)
    from @t
  ) as t
where code = min_code ;
```

Or the `rank()` window function (or the `dense_rank()` one, they'll both work the same for the `rnk = 1` check):

```
select id, code, descriptor
from 
  ( select id, code, descriptor, 
           rnk = rank() over (partition by id order by code)
    from @t
  ) as t
where rnk = 1 ;
```

---

I was about to comment that there is no way to do this without subqueries of any kind (correlated, derived tables, ctes) but alas, there is. Not in 2008R2 but in 2012 version using one more window function.

**Note: Do not use this. The efficiency will probably be the worse. The following query might be good for an obfuscation contest but not for production.**

Instead, check the nice execution plan of the above 2nd query, when there is a suitable index.

Just for fun - and horror of the future maintainer of the code:

```
select distinct
    id, 
    code = min(code) over (partition by id),
    descriptor = 
        case when code = min(code) over (partition by id)
            then descriptor
            else first_value(descriptor) over 
                    (partition by id order by code, descriptor)
        end
from @t ;
```

Tested at [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e16a2/1)

Comment: The idea is to not use the sub-queries. This removes one sub-query, but introduces another.

Comment: @ajeh but keep in min that you can't use window aggregate in WHERE clause so you have to go for this.

Comment: @ajeh: This is a derived table and not a correlated subquery. But yes, they are both referred under the term "subquery".

Comment: @ajeh `The idea is to not use the sub-queries.` Why? Pointy-haired boss think that all subqueries are bad? As aasim stated, you can't use the alias of an expression like `rank()` or `row_number()` in the `WHERE` clause. So maybe you should go back to the drawing board and explain what problem you're actually trying to *solve* by removing any and all subqueries...

Comment: Clever but naughty. "Do not use this" should be in 400pt red font. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree. Good thing is the OP can't use it (not until they upgrade at least ;)

Answer (score 6):

Of course you could also write this using a CTE:

```
;WITH t AS
(
  SELECT id, code, descriptor, 
    min_code = MIN(code) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
  FROM @t
)
SELECT id, code, descriptor 
FROM t WHERE code = min_code;
```

You *cannot* say:

```
SELECT id, code, descriptor
FROM @t 
WHERE code = MIN(code) OVER (PARTITION BY id);
```

Because:

> Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
>   
> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Completely unclear on this:

> The idea is to not use the sub-queries.

But maybe whoever is blindly rejecting the idea of a subquery will not be wise enough to recognize that a CTE is just a subquery in different clothing. (The fact that a lot of people don't recognize a CTE on sight is both a blessing and a curse at times.)

Otherwise, please start over, and explain why you need to remove subqueries entirely. For some problems (like applying windowing functions), there is no alternative but to filter against them in a different scope - which means a subquery, derived table, CTE, etc... all flavors of a subquery.

Answer (score -8):

```
select m.id, min(m.code) as code, m.descriptor
from @t as m
group by m.id, m.descriptor
order by m.id, code
```

The *order by* is only there to produce the output table in the same order as your example, but it is entirely unnecessary.

Revision to include the comment I added below - handling duplicates:

```
select a.id, a.code, b.descriptor
from
(
select id, min(code) as code
from
(
select id, code
from @t
group by id,code
) as a
group by id
) as a
inner join
@t as b
on b.id = a.id and a.code = b.code
```

No subselects, no SQL 2012 special features.  Just SQL.  It can be done.

Comment: A downvote?  That's hilarious.

Comment: The group by on descriptor is probably wrong. It just happen to return the expected resultset using the test data in the question.

Comment: "Probably wrong?"  Extremely humorous.

Comment: Yes you are right. Your answer is wrong so here is a -1 from me to.

Comment: Given the dataset, the query I supplied provides the same result set as the OP's.  You don't qualify *why* my answer is wrong.  So, I'll tell you:  The answer I provided doesn't account for duplicates.  To handle duplicates, the query would be: 
    select a.id, a.code, b.descriptor
    from
    (
    select id, min(code) as code
   from
    (
    select id, code
    from @t
    group by id,code
    ) as a
    group by id
   ) as a
   inner join
   @t as b
   on b.id = a.id and a.code = b.code

Comment: What do you mean by "no subselects"? Does `select ... from (select ... from (select ... from ...` qualify as no subselects?

Comment: The first query is wrong because it would only work under the assumption that for every code in the same id, there are exactly the same descriptors. This assumption fits with the example provided (all ids and codes have 10,20,30 descriptors.) I find this highly unlikely with real data. Just add a row with `3, c7, 5` and the query will fail.

Comment: The second query will give the wanted output but it has 2 (and nested) derived tables, one of them being entirely redundant. The same could have been accomplished with only derived table (with `group by id`) and then the join.

Comment: And the claim "no subselects" is just wrong. You have two derived tables (named `a`). Unless you mean something else with sub-selects.